# TestCafe docker image doesn't run on a Gitlab runner

Tags: docker, testing, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-machine, testcafe

**Setup**:

- Specific runner (Gitlab runner configured on EC2)
- TestCafe job using docker image:

  ```
    e2e:
      image:
        name: testcafe/testcafe
        entrypoint: ['/bin/sh', '-c']
      stage: e2e
      only:
        - develop
      tags:
        - myrunner
      dependencies: []
      script:
        - <my_script_here>
  ```
- runner config:

  ```
    [runners.docker]
      tls_verify = false
      image = "node:12-slim"
      privileged = true
      disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
      oom_kill_disable = false
      disable_cache = false
      volumes = ["/cache"]
      shm_size = 0
  ```

**Problem**:

The job fails as soon as I use the specific runner, doesn't even start tests, doesn't let me run any command. When using a shared runner, the job runs just fine.

From the gitlab CI log:

```
    Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
    sh: write error: Invalid argument            
    Cleaning up file based variables
    ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Logs on the runner machine don't say much, the only thing I found is: `WARNING: Failed to process runner`

NOTE: I suspect I'm missing something in the configuration of the machine.

Runner configured according to:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html#specific-runners
- https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2017/11/23/autoscale-ci-runners/

Comment: There are similar issues in the TestCafe repository, but we still cannot reproduce them: [#5645](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5645), [#5421](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/5421). Could you please provide full build and runner logs and try to use the `testcafe/testcafe:1.9.0-rc.1` image?

Comment: thank you, switching the image helped! Weird part was that the latest image was working fine with shared runners and not with my own runner. I need a few days to get to this work as it's quite a busy time, would it still be useful for you at that point?

Comment: Yes, it would be great if you provide detailed information.
If possible, please also create a new issue [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues).